# Does the left adjoint to the forgetful functor have another left adjoint?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

Consider $F: Top \rightarrow Set$ the forgetful functor from the category of topological spaces into the category of sets. I know that its left adjoint is the functor which gives the set a discrete topology. Does this functor have a left adjoint of its own? Intuitively i feel like the answer should be yes, but I have no clue how to prove it.

Comment: That functor doesn't preserve infinite products, so it can't have a left adjoint.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Could you point to a source or some example of a product that isn't preserved?

Comment: For example, the product topology on $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \{ 0, 1 \}$, with the discrete topology on $\{ 0, 1 \}$, is not the discrete topology.

Comment: @DanielSchepler And same reasoning could be applied to the right adjoint and coproducts, is that correct? The right adjoint is the functor that gives the set the indiscrete topology, and this doesn't preserve coproducts?

Comment: I believe so, yes.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I'm not sure I understand why we can't apply this reasoning to show that the functor that gives the set an indiscrete topology isn't the right adjoint to the forgetful one. It has to preserve limits as the right adjoint, but it seems to me that it also doesnt preserve infinite products, since the product topology isn't the indiscrete topology as well. Could you point out the mistake in this reasoning?

Comment: @user525008 Indiscrete topologies are preserved under products but not coproducts.

Comment: The discrete space functor does admit a left adjoint, namely the functor of connected components, when you restrict to locally connected spaces. So this lack of a left adjoint is a deficiency, reflecting the presence of pathological spaces, for many purposes.

Comment: The subcategory of locally connected spaces doesn't admit equalizers, though, the way the full category does - for example, the equalizer of $d(x, \{ \frac{1}{n} \}), 0 : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which would have to be $\{ \frac{1}{n} \} \cup \{ 0 \}$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I just mentioned locally connected spaces for simplicity. There's no problem in finding a model of topology admitting all limits and colimits in which every space is locally connected-the category of simplicial sets is a well known example.

Answer (score 3):

The discrete topology functor $D$ does not preserve infinite products.  For example, the product topology on $\prod_{n=1}^\infty D(\{ 0, 1 \})$ (which gives the categorical product in $\mathbf{Top}$) is not the discrete topology.

It follows that $D$ cannot have a left adjoint.